# is there a way to slow down translate animation while its being executed?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-coordinatorlayout

How can I control the speed of the animation? The translate animation goes from bottom to top and I'd like to slow down the animation during the time its being executed. How can I achieve this? Here is what I have:

```
public void SlideToAbove() {

    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

    slide.setDuration(300);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    toolBar.startAnimation(slide);

    final Animation finalSlide = slide;
    slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {


        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }


        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }


        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
                    toolBar.getWidth(), toolBar.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
            finalSlide.setFillAfter(true);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
slide =new TranslateAnimation(-100f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
slide.setDuration(600);
```

Comment: add more if you want this to be slowest.

Comment: I meant how to slow down the time when the bottom gets to the top. For example, when the user clicks the animation begins, it takes the bottom to reach to the top within 4 seconds.

Comment: slide =new TranslateAnimation(-100f, 0f, 0f, 0f); mainly duration helps but you can try this